# SCP Connection Refuses while SSH Works [Ubuntu 22.04]

Tags: networking, scp

Running Ubuntu 22.04 as a server and I’m encountering an issue with SCP. While I can SSH into it without any issues, attempting to transfer files via SCP [From a Windows 10 Machine on the same network], results in a “Connection refused” error.

```py
> scp -vvvv -P 22 "Pokémon Diamond & Pearl Sinnoh Map.jpg" ubuntu@192.168.0.110:./
```

```py
Executing: program ssh.exe host 192.168.0.110, user ubuntu, command scp -v -t ./
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Dark/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.0.110 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.110 [192.168.0.110] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10061, io:0000020BB6497460
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.110 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.110 port 22: Connection refused
lost connection
```

### I've tried the following:

- Allowing Port 22

```shell
$ sudo ufw allow 22
```

```shell
$ sudo ufw status 
Status: inactive
```

- Resetting .bashrc

```bash
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

- Verifying the status of the SSH daemon

```py
$ systemctl status ssh
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-01-27 21:36:24 JST; 3s ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 28095 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 28096 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1660)
     Memory: 1.6M
        CPU: 65ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─28096 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"

Jan 27 21:36:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jan 27 21:36:24 ubuntu sshd[28096]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jan 27 21:36:24 ubuntu sshd[28096]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jan 27 21:36:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

My understanding is that SCP works by using SSH as a link, no? Or am I overlooking something here?

`Edit:` I explored both ports 22 and 8022 [based on info I found online], but neither appears to be functional. Below is the SCP command I executed for port 8022:

```py
scp -vvvv -P 8022 "Pokémon Diamond & Pearl Sinnoh Map.jpg" ubuntu@192.168.0.110:./
```

### Update [As requested by @user68186]:

I run both `ssh` and `scp` via `cmd` within `Windows Terminal`.

```py
> ssh ubuntu@192.168.0.110
ubuntu@192.168.0.110's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1037-raspi aarch64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Sat Jan 27 22:58:44 JST 2024

  System load:  0.0068359375       Temperature:            48.7 C
  Usage of /:   58.7% of 28.94GB   Processes:              280
  Memory usage: 47%                Users logged in:        2
  Swap usage:   11%                IPv4 address for wlan0: 192.168.0.110

 * Strictly confined Kubernetes makes edge and IoT secure. Learn how MicroK8s
   just raised the bar for easy, resilient and secure K8s cluster deployment.

   https://ubuntu.com/engage/secure-kubernetes-at-the-edge

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

254 updates can be applied immediately.
175 of these updates are standard security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

30 additional security updates can be applied with ESM Apps.
Learn more about enabling ESM Apps service at https://ubuntu.com/esm


Last login: Sat Jan 27 19:29:14 2024 from 192.168.0.102
```

## Update Final:

Given the considerable time spent troubleshooting this `SCP` transfer issue, and considering that `SFTP` and `Samba` are viable alternatives that are already working, I've decided to utilize them instead and allocate my time elsewhere. I'm grateful for everyone's insights and assistance thus far. Feel free to continue investigating further if you wish. Cheers!

Comment: Have you looked at the auth logs on the Ubuntu machine when you attempt the connection to see if that gives any clues? e.g. `tail -f /var/log/auth.log`

Comment: Please post some output of the working `ssh -vvv ubuntu@192.168.0.110` command. For some reason, despite the `systemctl` I still suspect the wrong port.

Comment: I’ve successfully used the OP’s original command in Powershell in Windows 10 that included the port explicitly specified with `-P 22` as well as the `./` notation for the destination directory. It works for me. So this isn’t the problem. I think the clue to the problem is with the error: `finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10061, io:0000020BB6497460`. But I haven’t been able to find an explanation yet.

Comment: @user68186 When I successfully used the OP’s original command to connect to one of my servers, I got these two errors as well: `debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Dark/.ssh/config error:2 debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2`. Even so, it didn’t prevent me from connecting and transferring a file. So I’m thinking this isn’t an issue. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Does this help? [Why doesn’t SCP work while SSH does?](https://superuser.com/questions/395356/why-doesn-t-scp-work-while-ssh-does)

Comment: Is `openssh-client` installed on your server? This includes `scp` which needs to be installed on remote machine for `scp` to work. What’s the output of `apt-cache policy openssh-client`?

Comment: @codlord After executing `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` and attempting the `SCP` transfer, 
 no new entries appear during the connection attempt.

Comment: @mpboden Yes, `openssh-client` is already installed on the server.